# Can't post (create) 3rd level nested model in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC

Tags: database, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm at the end of my thoughts. It's been days. I can't figure out how to validate and then create a new database model from deep-nested models.

I have `Offer` and `Order` tables which share `Company/Currency/Contact` tables so I decided, instead of having `Offer.Company`, `Order.Company`, to create a table `SharedInfo` and have it `Offer.SharedInfo.Company` and `Order.SharedInfo.Comapany` which can be the same.

Shortened for brevity

**Company.cs**:

```
namespace memo.Models
{
    public partial class Company
    {
        [Key]
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You have to fill the name of the Company")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**SharedInfo.cs**:

```
namespace memo.Models
{
    public class SharedInfo
    {
        public SharedInfo()
        {
            Company = new Company();
        }

        [Key]
        public int SharedInfoId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Subject { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
```

**Offer.cs**:

```
namespace memo.Models
{
    public partial class Offer
    {
        public Offer()
        {
            SharedInfo = new SharedInfo();
        }

        [Key]
        public int OfferId { get; set; }

        public int SharedInfoId { get; set; }
        public virtual SharedInfo SharedInfo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My view model for `Create.cshtml` file is (again, for brevity shortened but this fills my combobox and references the `Offer`):

```
namespace memo.ViewModels
{
    public class OfferViewModel
    {
        public Offer Offer { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CompanyList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now I want to create a new offer where I select `CompanyId` from a combobox.

**Offers/Create.cshtml**:

```
@model memo.ViewModels.OfferViewModel

<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-10 personal-info">
        <form class="card" role="form" autocomplete="on" asp-action="Create" method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label asp-for="Offer.SharedInfo.Subject" class="required col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <span class="has-float-label">
                    <input asp-for="Offer.SharedInfo.Subject" class="form-control" type="text" />
                    <label asp-for="Offer.SharedInfo.Subject"></label>
                </span>
                <span asp-validation-for="Offer.SharedInfo.Subject" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="required col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <select class="form-control selectpicker" asp-for="Offer.SharedInfo.Company.CompanyId" asp-items="@Model.CompanyList"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Offer.SharedInfo.Company.CompanyId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here I select a company which gives me the `CompanyId`, no problem there.

But now, when I click on `Create Offer` button to Post the form, the validation fails...

**Offers/OffersController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Offer offer)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            offer.CreatedBy = User.GetLoggedInUserName();
            offer.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;

            await _db.AddAsync(offer);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

}

Validation tells me that:

> SubKey={Name}, Key="offer.SharedInfo.CompanyName", ValidationState=Invalid

What I want to achieve is to Create 2 new tables. `SharedInfo` which will reference the Company by ID I selected and then `Offer`, which will reference the new `SharedInfo` record.

Am I doing something horribly wrong? It's telling me I have to "it's required" specify Company.Name but when I select the company by it's ID, it should know the name...

I even tried in the controller to specify `_context.Offer.SharedInfo.Company = _context.Company.Where(x => x.CompanyId == offer.SharedInfo.Company.CompanyId)` but that fails in >> Validation << because, I think, the SharedInfo is not yet created? Don't know. I'm totally at the end with my thoughts.

Comment: Where is a GET for Offers/Create.cshtml?

Comment: The model validation does not related to and will not be influenced by database operation.

Comment: Sergey: yeah, that would help for sure if I wrote that also. Should I edit it? 
@Rena: Hi, I've figured the problem, it was a stupid mistake but thanks to yours and Sergey's answers it resolved. Should I edit my original post and write an aswer by myself? I've never done that till now.

Comment: Hi @SonGokussj4,you need post a answer instead of edit your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Model validation will validate the whole model if you specify any of their property in your razor view.For you contains input named `Offer.SharedInfo.Company.CompanyId` and `Offer.SharedInfo.Subject`,model validation will validate all the properties in `Company` model and 'SharedInfo' model although you do not set CompanyName input.

And I think you may be confused that `Offer.SharedInfo.CompanyId` which is required but you also do not set input in razor view.Because it is an `int` type,you could see that it will receive default value `0` if you do not pass the value to backend.And `0` is a valid value for `int` type,that is why the validation for `Offer.SharedInfo.CompanyId` succeed.

For your requirement,you want to skip the validation of CompanyName,you could use `ModelState.Remove(keyname)` like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Offer offer)
{
    ModelState.Remove("Offer.SharedInfo.CompanyName");//from your error message,it should be the key name
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```